# ASP.NET Core dynamic assembly (dll) mvc (attribute) routing

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using the AssemblyLoaderContext in ASP.NET Core 1.1 to load a dll in my plugin folder in my MVC main application with the 'LoadAssemblyFromPath' function. However, I'd like to the attribute routing of my plugin dll's controller to work in my main application. For this I should be able to clear and rebuild the MVC routing. How is this possible to do? It used to be doable in MVC 4-5 using GlobalConfiguration, but as I read on some blogs, it was not a best practice and so the GlobalConfiguration is removed from ASP.NET Core.

So, how can I rebuild the MVC routes, not from the startup class, because I don't want to restart my web application? 
I'm aiming for an experience like Wordpress and Drupal, where you upload the dll in this case to the server and in the UI, press activate to load this plugin.

Comment: At which point you load your dynamic module ?

Comment: I do this in a controller (I will be extracting this to a service with a lot more checks and actions when I get the core stuff working) by using a get method like api/modules/activate which receives the ID of the module to activate and searches this dll in the plugins folder.  Then I use the LoadAssemblyFromPath from the injected AssemblyLoaderContext object

Comment: If you load extension during Startup then you might change route. As you said you want to change controller level. I will ask that please have look at project on github https://github.com/ExtCore/ExtCore. This will might help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that project. I've already looked at that one before. However, it does not work with Attribute Routing. Also, this requires the application to restart, which I'd like to avoid also.